# Patent is illegal, open sourced decades ago

Tags: prior-art, us20150042260

In reference to the patent: [US 2015/0042260](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150042260)

This patent is illegal.

Intellectual properties belong to HECTOR PEREZ TORRES, ARKRESEARCH, PR.
It has been open sourced since at least 1999.

The building specs have been on panaceabocaf.org since 2008.

The [EVGRAY Yahoo Group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/EVGRAY/info) has openly been discussing the [rotoverter (RV)](http://peswiki.com/index.php/Directory:Rotoverter) for at least 12 years and other free energy groups also.

Answer (score 1):

Patent applications can't be illegal unless they are disclosing trade secrets that fall under some form of legally binding non-disclosure agreement (NDA). Anyone not under such an NDA can *attempt* to patent whatever they want. However, this is ultimately a negotiation with the patent authorities over what constitutes a novel and non-obvious invention.

This is a Patent *Application*, which only means that someone is applying for a patent. If there is Prior Art publicly available, then it is up to the Patent Examiner at the USPTO (or the examiner at WIPO, because there was also a WIPO (Worldwide Patent) applied for, [WO 2013/134161 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013134161A1). The examination process exists to prevent patents from being granted over already-existing ideas. The examiners at the USPTO and at WIPO actually do a really excellent job at finding Prior Art.

Keep in mind that just because a specific idea is in the title, abstract or description of a patent application (or even in the claims), it doesn't necessarily mean that the Patent Grant(s) will cover it. In an application or grant, the most important things to look at are the independent claims. This is what describes the invention, regardless of anything else in the document. These might go through several revisions before the examiners agree that something novel has been created.

In the case of the application you referred to:

> **Claim 1.** An energy-saving device, comprising:
>
> - at least one starting capacitor;
> - at least one running capacitor; and
> - at least one power factor capacitor,
> - all in electrical communication with a power supply and at least one induction motor,
> - wherein the power supply needs to supply a much smaller input than the output current of the at least one induction motor after the induction motor has been running for at least from one second to about 30 minutes.
>
> **Claim 6.** An energy-saving device, comprising:
>
> - at least one starting capacitor;
> - at least one running capacitor; and
> - at least one power factor capacitor,
> - an automatically adjustable tuning system with computer algorithms for progressively interconnecting said starting, running and power factor capacitors to achieve the lowest possible input,
> - all in electrical communication with a power supply and at least one induction motor, wherein the power supply is tuned to need a much smaller input than the output current of the at least one induction motor after the induction motor has been running for at least from one second to about 30 minutes.

These claims are so broad that they will likely fail several tests for novelty and inventive step.

If you consider device described in the above claims to already be in the Public Domain, then there are some things you can do to help the patent examiners find the appropriate material, for which you can find references [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/found-prior-art).

In fact, some applications are filed and abandoned solely to put material into the Public Domain in a place that is easily findable by patent examiners, since online forums are not considered to contain persistent material. This effectively prevents anyone else from seeking broad claims in a particular area.